# JSP compilation exception in weblogic 10.3.6 but works in weblogic 8.4

Tags: c, jstl

I'm working on migrating my source code from weblogic 8v4 to weblogic 10.3.6 and been struggling with a JSP file that has compilation issues with ant scripts. This works well with weblogic 8v4 but not with weblogic 10.3.6. Been looking for resolution over google for quite sometime but of no use. Any help with this is much appreciated.

Please let me know if any additional piece of code is required in providing a resolution to this.

```
   [wlappc] There are 1 nested errors:
   [wlappc] weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: jspc failed with errors :weblogic.servlet.jsp.CompilationException: editAdjustment.jsp:436:212: The page failed validation from validator: "Illegal text inside "c:choose" tag: "<input ...".".
   [wlappc]                                                                 onclick="loadCheckHiddenValue(this); toggleSectznRows(this.checked); disableNonSectznRows(this.checked); changeFieldState('regulatoryVal<c:out value='${varStatus.count}'/>','<c:out value='${varStatus.count}' />')" 
   [wlappc]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^----------------------------------^
   [wlappc] editAdjustment.jsp:436:212: The page failed validation from validator: "Illegal child tag in "c:choose" tag: "c:out" tag".
   [wlappc]                                                                 onclick="loadCheckHiddenValue(this); toggleSectznRows(this.checked); disableNonSectznRows(this.checked); changeFieldState('regulatoryVal<c:out value='${varStatus.count}'/>','<c:out value='${varStatus.count}' />')"
```

Comment: Please post the relevant block of code around `editAdjustment.jsp:436:212`, or if possible upload the complete `JSP` and post the link here. Also please describe what is the `JSTL` version that you are using in your project.

Comment: @Evandro - I wanted to upload the whole JSP, but do not know a way to do that. This even won't let me copy more than 500 characters of code. The versions are as follows..... JSTL jar file - v1.2 and c.tld - v1.2 and fmt.tld - v1.1

Comment: Post your piece of code in an external site then. Try http://textuploader.com for instance. Just add the link to the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Here is the link for the jsp code. http://textuploader.com/9gju

Comment: @Evandro - I've also uploaded the error details while building the code using the ant scripts at - http://textuploader.com/9gj3

Comment: What are the types of `varStatus` and `status` variables? Can you upload them as well? I was only able to replicate that validation message adding hardcoded HTML comments (`<!-- -->`) inside the `<c:choose>`.

Comment: @Evandro - which variables you are asking about? I thought they are the attributes of forEach tags from c.tld.